# Difference betwen any other vs all other

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between ' he has to do all other works vs he has to any other works.

Comment: Plural ***works*** isn't idiomatic in this context. The "uncountable noun" version is *He has to do any/all other **work***, or you can use a countable noun: *He has to do any/all other **jobs / tasks***.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather unnusual to combine "have to" with "any".  You would use "any" with "can" or "may", to mean you have a free choice.

> You may do any of these tasks.  (you may pick one or a few)

> You may do all of these tasks (you may pick them all, but it isn't required)

Or you could use "any" with a negative "don't have to"

> You don't have to do any of these tasks  (you may do none of them)

> You don't have to do all of these tasks (This suggests you should do some of them)

But with a positive instruction you would use "all"

> You have to do all of these tasks.

Note I've changed the example. That is because "all other works" is not idiomatic.